# python re match no match behavior

Tags: python, regex

Greeting Dear community.
It seems to be when re.match find no match, it shows the error. Is it an exeception ? I am using spyder as my IDE and run the code from there

```
import re
import sys
def extract_year(line):
    #mat=re.search(r'Popularity\s+in\s+\d{4}',line)
    #mat=re.search(r'Popularity\s+in\s+[(19)(20)]\d{2}',line)   

    mat=re.search(r'Popularity\s+in\s+(19[0-9][0-9]|200[0-9]|201[0-9])',line)
    """
    if  __debug__:
        print mat.group(1)
        print mat.group()
    """        
    try:
        return mat.group(1)
    #print mat.group(2)
    except:
        e = sys.exc_info()  
        print e
        return ""

extract_year(' <h3 align="center">Popularity in 1898</h3>')
extract_year(' <h3 align="center">Popularity in 2018</h3>')   
extract_year(' <h3 align="center">Popularity in 1988</h3>')   
extract_year('cellpadding="2 cellspacing="0 summary="Popularity for top 1000"><caption><h2>Popularity in 1908</h2></caption>')
```

Why I got this in the console output ? Is it throwing an exception when there is no match ? If so, why it doesnt catch it in the try block ?

```
 extract_year(' <h3 align="center">Popularity in 1898</h3>')

    **(<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>, AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'",), <traceback object at 0x0000000013739748>)
    Out[98]: ''**

    extract_year(' <h3 align="center">Popularity in 2018</h3>')   

    Out[99]: '2018'

    extract_year(' <h3 align="center">Popularity in 1988</h3>')   

    Out[100]: '1988'

    extract_year('cellpadding="2 cellspacing="0 summary="Popularity for top 1000"><caption><h2>Popularity in 1908</h2></caption>') 

    Out[101]: '1908'
```

Answer (score 0):

if there is no match, then [re.search](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.search)() returns None, so you cannot access its .group method.

Answer (score 0):

When you get no match, `search` returns `None` so trying to call `group` on None is obviously going to fail and raise an exception, you are catching that exception so why you are seeing the `'exceptions.AttributeError'...`  because you are printing `e` i.e the `sys.exc_info()` in the except not seeing an error thrown.

Answer (score -1):

re.search returns None if it can't find a match.

```
import re


def extract_year(line):
    """Write a docstring for your function"""
    mat = re.search(r'Popularity in (\d{4})', line)
    if mat is None:
        raise ValueError('No year found.')
    else:
        return mat.group(1)

print extract_year(' <h3 align="center">Popularity in 1898</h3>')
print extract_year(' <h3 align="center">Popularity in 2018</h3>')
print extract_year(' <h3 align="center">Popularity in 1988</h3>')
print extract_year('cellpadding="2 cellspacing="0 summary="Popularity for top 1000"><caption><h2>Popularity in 1908</h2></caption>')
print extract_year('no year here')
```